# Scan qr code, but take a picture if cannot recognize qr code

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, zxing

I am using ZXing barcode scanner, but some devices are unable to quickly read QR codes. A fix I am seeing is to take a picture of the code, and read the scan the code from the image.

I tried putting SurfaceView and ZXingScannerView on top of each other, and setting the surface view visibility to invisible. But they conflict with each other.

Any idea on how to do this?
Thanks!